# cross_val_predict is not producing the same number of variables after transforming data with a Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running into an value error when using `cross_val_predict()`. For my project I want to test the performance of my model based on different values of k in SelectKBest(). The maximum value of k is equal to the number of variables in my dataset (447 variables).

One of my evaluation method is a confusion matrix based on cross validation. Prior to creating a confusion matrix I transform the data and tune a model using sklearn Pipeline and RandomizedSearchCV. For this I use the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import loguniform, uniform, randint
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
  X, 
  y, 
  test_size=0.2, 
  random_state=41, 
  stratify= y, 
  shuffle= True
)

# Create pipeline
numeric_pipe = Pipeline([
  ('scale', MinMaxScaler()),
  ('variance', VarianceThreshold(0)),
])

nominal_pipe = Pipeline([
  ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(
    sparse= False, 
    drop= None, 
    handle_unknown='ignore',
  )),
  ('variance', VarianceThreshold(.8 * (1 - .8)))
])

binary_pipe = Pipeline([
  ('variance', VarianceThreshold(.8 * (1 - .8)))
])

pipe = Pipeline([
  ('preprocess', ColumnTransformer([
    ('numeric', numeric_pipe, numeric_vars),
    ('nominal', nominal_pipe, nominal_vars),
    ('binary', binary_pipe, binary_vars)
  ], remainder= 'drop', n_jobs= -1)),
  ('mi', SelectKBest(partial(mutual_info_classif, random_state=42, n_neighbors= 10), k= 447)),
  ('predictor', RandomForestClassifier()),
], verbose= 2)

rf_params = {
  'predictor__bootstrap': [True],
  'predictor__ccp_alpha': loguniform(0.001, 0.01),
  'predictor__class_weight': [None],
  'predictor__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
  'predictor__max_depth': randint(1, 100),,
  'predictor__max_features': ['auto'],
  'predictor__max_leaf_nodes': [None],
  'predictor__max_samples': [None],
  'predictor__min_impurity_decrease': [0.0],
  'predictor__min_impurity_split': [None],
  'predictor__min_samples_leaf': loguniform(0.0001, 1),
  'predictor__min_samples_split': loguniform(0.0001, 1),
  'predictor__min_weight_fraction_leaf': [0],
  'predictor__n_estimators': randint(100, 1000),
  'predictor__n_jobs': [-1],
  'predictor__oob_score': [False],
  'predictor__random_state': [12, 78, 35, 245],
  'predictor__verbose': [0],
  'predictor__warm_start': [True]
}

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits= 10, shuffle= True, random_state= 42) 

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
  estimator= pipe,
  param_distributions= rf_params,
  n_iter= 10,
  scoring= "f1_weighted",
  n_jobs= -1,
  cv= cv,
  refit= True,
  verbose= 2,
  random_state= 42,
  return_train_score= True
)

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I print the number of variables left when I transform the data I get 447:

```py
print(random_search.best_estimator_[:-1].transform(X_train).shape[1])
```

Ouptut:

```
447
```

When I try `cross_val_predict`::

```py
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(random_search.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, cv= cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose= 2)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features = 446; got 447. Use k='all' to return all features.
```

with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 608, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 862, in _fit_and_predict
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 330, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 296, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 355, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 693, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py", line 352, in fit
    self._check_params(X, y)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py", line 525, in _check_params
    % (X.shape[1], self.k))
ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features = 446; got 447. Use k='all' to return all features.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1173964809015648> in <module>
----> 1 y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(random_search.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, cv= cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose= 2)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, groups, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, method)
    771     prediction_blocks = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_predict)(
    772         clone(estimator), X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
--> 773         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    774 
    775     # Concatenate the predictions

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1015 
   1016             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1017                 self.retrieve()
   1018             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1019             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    907             try:
    908                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 909                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    910                 else:
    911                     self._output.extend(job.get())

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    560         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    561         try:
--> 562             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    563         except LokyTimeoutError:
    564             raise TimeoutError()

/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features = 446; got 447. Use k='all' to return all features.
```

However when I use cross_validate or cross_val_score everything works well:

```py
y_train_pred = cross_validate(random_search.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, scoring = "f1_weighted", cv= cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose= 2)
```

```py
y_train_pred = cross_val_score(random_search.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, scoring = "f1_weighted", cv= cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose= 2)
```

I have solved the problem by first transforming the data and than apply cross_val_predict() but this is not the desired solution as it creates data leakage.:

```py
model = random_search.best_estimator_
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(model[-1], model[:-1].transform(X_train), y_train, cv= cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose= 2)
```

To my understanding the error comes up due to the variance threshold because the variance changes for when using the 10-fold cross validation. This results in different number of variables.

But why no error appears in `cross_val_score()` and `cross_validate()`? Am I missing something, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Unfortunately I am not able to share my data due to a Non Disclosure Agreement. I tried to replicate it using `make_classification()` but without any luck.